# How do you extract derived types from a generic list?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class with these properties:

```
public List<CommitmentItem<ITransaction, ITransactionItem>> CommitmentItems;
public List<CapitalCallCommitmentItem> CapitalCallCommitmentItems;
```

`CapitalCallCommitmentItem` inherits CommitmentItem. I want the `CapitalCallCommitmentItems` property to return all `CommitmentItems` where the type is of CapitalCallCommitmentItem. So I tried this code:

```
get
{                
    return CommitmentItems
        .Where(c => c.GetType() == typeof(CapitalCallCommitmentItem))
        .Select(c => (CapitalCallCommitmentItem)c)
        .ToList();
}
```

However, I get an error saying:

Error   1   Cannot convert type 'Models.CommitmentItem' to 'Models.CapitalCallCommitmentItem'

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Question name has no meaning :(

Comment: @Restutat - it is a generic question name :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `OfType` extension method.

```
return CommitmentItems.OfType<CapitalCallCommitmentItem>().ToList();
```

In your code, although you're filtering on the subtype in the `where` clause, it is still going to return the general type of the list. `OfType` will return an enumerable of the provided type.

Answer (score 2):

be sure that it is convertible/castable/oftype.

then try eg
[.Cast<T>()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx)
[.OfType<T>()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx)

Comment: For OfType it doesn't even has to be castable.

Comment: i know, but sort of... it should rather state "of type" :)

Answer (score 1):

You're on to it. The following works fine at my machine. The resulting list will be of type `List<CapitalCallCommitmentItem>`:

```
get
{                
    return CommitmentItems
        .Where(c => c is CapitalCallCommitmentItem)
        .Select(c => c as CapitalCallCommitmentItem)
        .ToList();
}
```

**Update:** ...but yeah, `CommitmentItems.OfType<CapitalCallCommitmentItem>` is superior.